# Set of Normal subgroups is a sublattice of a set of subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lattice-orders

I need to show that if $ G$ is a group then $\mathcal N(G)$ is a sublattice of $S(G)$.
Obviously $N(G) \subseteq S(G) $. How do I show that operations join and meet agree with those of the original lattice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to show that the join and meet of two normal subgroups $H,K$ are also normal.

The meet of $H,K$ is $H \cap K$, and it is easy to verify that the intersection of normal subgroups is normal.

The join of $H,K$ is $HK$, which we can show is also normal:
$$ x hk x^{-1} = x h x^{-1} x k x^{-1} = h'k' $$
(Also, because one of the factors is normal, $HK =KH$)

Comment: I know the definition of sublattice as subset of Lattice L where the lattice operations are same as that in the main lattice. I am confusd how does that definition fit in the solution you wrote

Comment: @Anurag This shows the join/meet operations on the original lattice when applied to normal subgroups yield normal subgroups, hence the subset of normal subgroups is closed under the original lattice operations. Now try to see that the normal join/meet must equal the original lattice's join/meet.

Comment: Cool. So it means whenever I need to show something to be a sublattice. I first prove it to be a subset and then use the join/meet of original lattice and show that the subset is closed under those operations. Thanks :)

Comment: @Anurag That is correct; the meet/join operations on a subposet of a lattice, when they exist, are bounded respectively by the meet/join in the original lattice, which implies if the subposet is closed under the lattice operations it is itself a lattice with the same operations.

Answer (score 0):

Take two normal subgroups $H$ and $K$ of $G$. The meet of those is simply the intersection of them, which you should have no problem in proving to be also a normal subgroup (simply use the definition). The joij of them is the set of elements of the form $a_1\cdots a_n$, with $a_i\in H\cup K$, and this is also a normal subgroup of $G$ (associativity is crucial here).